# Why does javaScript / jQuery seem to ignore my IF statement on event bubbling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, event-bubbling

I am sure it is just me not understanding JavaScript fundamentals properly. But could someone point out as why I have the impression that my if statement evaluates to true, on event bubbling, even though the statement inside the if statement should evaluate to false ?

The if(sFormula > 168) seem to work as intended when I press the html < a > tag once at a time, but if I rapidly click on it, everything seems to go crazy.

Here is a jsFiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/twimB/pGHrP/ and below is just a snippet of the whole.

I would greatly appreciate  if someone could take his/her time to explain.

Thanks.

Html

```
<a href="#" id="right">&raquo;</a>
```

jQuery

```
$("#right").click(function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if(busy == false){
        busy = true ;
        var parentMargin = $(".wrap").offset().left;
        var parentWidth = $(".wrap").width();
        var carouselMargin = $(".block").offset().left;
        var carouselWidth = $(".block").width();
        var rFormula = carouselWidth - ((parentMargin - carouselMargin) + parentWidth);
        $(".pLeft").text("");
        $(".pRight").text("if ( rFormula > 0 ) {perform slide} fFormula is: " + rFormula);
        if(rFormula > 168){
            $(".block").animate({"left": "-=168px"}, "slow");
        }
        busy = false ;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Felix, by using the if statement I am trying to prevent the sliding from taking place if the last object in the .block element is shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.animate()` method doesn't stop the script execution. What happens is that it starts the animation and script execution continues, and `busy` is immediately set to false.

What you need is to set the flag only after the animation has finished using a callback function:

```
if(rFormula > 168){
    busy = true;
    $(".block").animate({"left": "-=168px"}, "slow", function() { busy = false });
}
```

(Note that I also moved setting the flag here because there's no benefit in setting it before the animation begins.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pGHrP/1/ (I updated only the right button.)